# Density of universe during recombination

Tags: cosmology

How can I calculate the density of the Universe at [recombination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recombination_%28cosmology%29)?

Answer (score 3):

Recombination occurred at a red shift of about Z = 1100 i.e. the length scale has increased by a factor of 1100 (strictly speaking 1100 + 1) since then. So if you take the current density and multiply by $1100^3$ you'll get the density at recombination.

However your question isn't as simple as it seems. Do you mean the baryon density, the baryon + dark matter density or the total density? The current total density is pretty close to the critical density, and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Density_parameter) gives this as about five hydrogen atoms per cubic meter. The baryon density is about 4% of this and the dark matter density is about 21% of this. Five hydrogen atoms weigh $8.3 \times 10^{-24}$g, and multiplying this by $1100^3$ makes the total density at recombination about $10^{-14}$gm$^{-3}$.

Comment: Yes, I want to calculate total recombination density but how five hydrogen atom comes in equation.

Comment: The five hydrogen atoms per m$^3$ is the current critical density. The cosmic microwave background tells us the universe is flat, and for a flat universe the critical density can be calculated from the Hubble constant. If you do this it comes out as about $8.3 \times 10^{-24}$gm$^{-3}$, which is the same as 5 hydrogen atoms per m$^3$. Using five hydrogen atoms as the unit of weight is just a good way to visualise the density and relate it to something easy to remember.